# Killing children in classic and enhanced Baldur's gate 1 & 2 and Icewind Dale

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-2, baldurs-gate-enhanced, icewind-dale, baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

I am asking here, because I seem not to be able to find a definitive answer from a quick Google search and I believe I could run into spoilers when digging deeper (thus I am asking for a spoiler-free answer).

From the quick search I know you can kill children in:

- Baldur's gate
- Baldur's gate II

Is that correct?

What about:

- Baldur's gate Enhanced Edition
- Baldur's gate II Enhanced Edition
- Icewind Dale
- Icewind Dale Enhanced Edition

I think there is a similar problem in Fallout, i.e. you can kill children in US version but not in any other. Although you can apply a fix to the censored version. Can you apply a similar fix to BG or ID?

I believe there might be some people with attitude like "why would you even?". I simply hate such arbitrary constraints even though I would not violate them when playing. I completed all these games in their classical versions but I don't actually remember or even never knew if you can kill kids there because it was not my gaming style.

**UPDATE**

It seems that, as far as Fallout is concerned, GOG.com's version is uncensored. GOG offers Baldur's Gate EE: is this version the same as STEAM's?

Comment: You're asking abour quite a few different games in one question. You should proably break this into seperate questions either by game, or at least by series.

Comment: It would take some time to check to make it an answer - but all in all these are not different questions since AFAIK `you can kill children in every version of BG and ID` making further questions moot. Well, all but the version difference one - that deserves it's own question.

Comment: @Delthais, here: https://forums.beamdog.com/discussion/6615/invincible-children I found this: "[...] I was playing Icewind Dale in anticipation for Baldur's Gate: EE and I noticed that children cannot be killed. Found this out by casting an area of effect spell that accidentally netted one. They turn hostile but can't die. [...]"